# Error LNK2031, LNK2028, LNK2019, LNK2001

Tags: mysql, visual-c++, mysql-connector

So I was able to successfully build a program in visual c++ using a command prompt. It was a simple program to read from the database then write to the database based on some variable. So I decided to make it a lot more fancy and add a button. I linked everything up the same as I did before, posted the same code without the cout and cin, but I recieved this code

> 1>stdafx.obj : error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A00000D) "public: __clrcall sql::SQLString::~SQLString(void)" (??1SQLString@sql@@$$FQAM@XZ) referenced in function "public: virtual __clrcall sql::mysql::MySQL_Savepoint::~MySQL_Savepoint(void)" (??1MySQL_Savepoint@mysql@sql@@$$FUAM@XZ)
>
> 1>new test mysql.obj : error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A00001E) "public: __clrcall sql::SQLString::~SQLString(void)" (??1SQLString@sql@@$$FQAM@XZ) referenced in function "private: void __clrcall newtestmysql::Form1::mysqltest(void)" (?mysqltest@Form1@newtestmysql@@$$FA$AAMXXZ)
>
> 1>stdafx.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: __clrcall sql::SQLString::~SQLString(void)" (??1SQLString@sql@@$$FQAM@XZ)
>
> 1>new test mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __clrcall sql::SQLString::SQLString(char const * const)" (??0SQLString@sql@@$$FQAM@QBD@Z) referenced in function "private: void __clrcall newtestmysql::Form1::mysqltest(void)" (?mysqltest@Form1@newtestmysql@@$$FA$AAMXXZ)

The errors happen about 3 more times
Here is the code

```
    void mysqltest(){    
        try {    
  sql::Driver *driver;    
  sql::Connection *con;    
  sql::Statement *stmt;    
  sql::ResultSet *res;    
  sql::PreparedStatement *pstmt;    

  /* Create a connection */    
  driver = get_driver_instance();    
  con = driver->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3306", "root", "");    
  /* Connect to the MySQL test database */    
  con->setSchema("awesome");    

  stmt = con->createStatement();    
  stmt->execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test");    
  stmt->execute("CREATE TABLE test(id INT)");    
  delete stmt;    

  /* '?' is the supported placeholder syntax */    
  pstmt = con->prepareStatement("INSERT INTO test(id) VALUES (?)");    
  for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {    
    pstmt->setInt(1, i);    
    pstmt->executeUpdate();    
  }    
  delete pstmt;    

  /* Select in ascending order */    
  pstmt = con->prepareStatement("SELECT id FROM test ORDER BY id ASC");    
  res = pstmt->executeQuery();    

  /* Fetch in reverse = descending order! */    
  res->afterLast();    
  while (res->previous())    
  delete res;    

 delete pstmt;    
  delete con;    

}     
 catch (sql::SQLException &e) {    
}    
    }
```

Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: Please format your code properly

Comment: Yes it is... Still, you should provide some code, because People cannot know how to solve your linking-errors

Comment: Are you using `C++` or `C++/CLI`?

Comment: I think c++/cli, how could I be sure?

Comment: Check your project... I can't tell from your code, but according to the errors it seems that way...

Comment: possible duplicate of [LNK2028 and LNK2019 errors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9234549/lnk2028-and-lnk2019-errors)

Comment: yes it is c++/cli. Also I should let you know that there is more code in the project. It hooks up with a camera and retrieves a video from it. I had it working with just connecting to the camera, taking a video, then storing the video based on some value in a text file. My boss wanted me to make it read from a database instead of a text file, and this is the error I'm running into. I can make it work with just a command prompt but not with the simple button I have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first three errors refer to a `destructor` which cannot be found. This is what [LNK2028](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235590%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) says:

```
"exported_function" (decorated_name) referenced in function 
"function_containing_function_call" (decorated_name)
```

When attempting to import a native function into a pure image, remember that the implicit calling conventions differ between native and pure compilations

[LNK2001](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f6xx1b1z.aspx) says

```
unresolved external symbol "symbol"
```

Code references something (such as a function, variable, or label) that the linker can't find in the libraries and object files.

-> Have you implemented a destructor for the class?

And finally what [LNK2019](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/799kze2z.aspx) says

```
unresolved external symbol 'symbol' referenced in function 'function'
```

An undefined external symbol (symbol) was found in function. To resolve this error, provide a definition for symbol or remove the code that references it.

My guess is, your destructor is missing. Please see the links for reference.

Comment: So if I were to go back into the header files, I'll most likely won't see a destructor? The header files and library come from http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/cpp/. Is it because it's made for a console application?

Comment: Not the header files, but the implementation of the method. I can't tell exactly, because I don't know all of your code.

Comment: Which line? Please add it to your question

Comment: The one posted above in the question. That was what I added that started all these errors.

Comment: I just realized that in order to solve an earlier issue, I added /clr into the command line of the c/c++ properties. Those issues disappeared, but now I have a lot of warnings and an issue with something else in the code.
**1>c:\users\taycm_000\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\test-new\test\stdafx.h(28): error C3641: 'handleObjectEvent' : invalid calling convention '__stdcall ' for function compiled with /clr:pure or /clr:safe**    
is there a way to solve this without using /clr in the command line?